# hide s4-titlerow show search box

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, branding

I need some custom element to be added in the s4-titlerow, so what i did was to remove s4-titlerow using css as below

```
    #s4-titlerow{
    display:none!important;
}
```

but what i need is to show the default search box in the right side and add my app on the left. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do i instead of using `display:none;` which doesn't render the item, you can use `visibility:hidden;` and on the Searchbox element use `visibility:visible`

the code will look something like this:

```
#s4-titlerow 
{
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
    visibility: hidden;
}

#DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea 
{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Have a look at this for more reference: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the replay , when i added the above the search box is showing on the left and are overlapping with the custom app. please see the updated question with the image

Comment: Thanks Brannmar, I made a small change removed width: 800px; and got what i was looking for.